# How to change audio output device using VLC.Net

Tags: c#, .net, output, device, vlc

I am able to create media player like app using VLC.Net library. I am now trying to add a feature to be able to select the output device to play the media through. So far no luck. 
Has anyone ever done it?

Comment: What information do you already have? What about AudioOutputDevice.SetAsCurrent()? Do you already have the AudioOutputDevice? (You are talking about vlc.dotnet from zebobo5?)

Comment: I have the VLC.Net library from zebobo5. But I don't know how to use it to allow the user to select the desired output device. Any piece of code that could help direct me to that area will really help.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the source code I would try the following. I assume you have a VlcMediaPlayer at hand and created somewhere:

```
void DoAudio(VlcMediaPlayer player)
{
    IAudioManagement audioMgt = player.Audio;

    foreach(AudioOutputDescriptions descriptions in audioMgt.Outputs.All){

        foreach(AudioOutputDevice device in description.Devices){
            //enumerate them for display
            string audioName = device.LongName;

            // Or set it as output
            device.SetAsCurrent();
        }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error "{"Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible."}" on this line............ foreach(AudioOutputDescriptions descriptions in audioMgt.Outputs.All){

Comment: Unfortunately this sounds like a marshalling issue in vlc.net. It is wrapping the unmanaged vlc Lib of the vlc project and pinvokes on their functions. You would need to post a bug at https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/issues with the sample code that gives the error. If you have a stacktrace inside of vlc.dotnet I would add that too.

Comment: Thanks for you help Uwe. I ended up using libZplay library and I now have full control on selecting audio output device.